# Powershell website automation with getElements

Tags: html, powershell

New to powershell. I looked at some of the other examples in stack-overflow but didn't find the a solution.

My issue:
I am trying to fill out a form and cant insert into an input field for EMAIL. I tried `getElementByName` and `getElementsByTagName` and it cant find it. 
I tried looking it by `id="main-content"` but I must have done it wrong too.

Putting a value into `$pw` work because it has an ID, but i cant make it work with the others with no id.

I will have to make the email a string somehow. i think.

PowerShell:

```
While ( $ie.busy -eq $true){
    [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(2000)
}
$doc = $ie.document

$pw = $doc.getElementByID("passwd")
$pw.value = "$userPW"

$em = $doc.getElementsByTagName("p") |
where-object {$_.Name -eq "email"} |
ForEach-object { $_.value("some@email.her")}



#$email = $unID + $([char]64) + "DOMAINNAME" + $([char]46) + "com"
#$em.value = ($email -as [string])
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
<div class="content-box content-box-outer">
    <div class="content-box-content">
        <fieldset class="column-left">

            <p>
                 <label>Password</label>
                 <input name="passwd" id="passwd" type="password" text="Password" value="" autocomplete="off" class="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="text" text="Email" value="" class="">
            </p>


        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="column-right">

            <p>
                <label>Fax Number</label>
                <input name="fax" type="text" text="Fax Number" maxlength="64" value="" class="">
            </p>              
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: The tag name is INPUT, not P.

Comment: Thank you Tony, I thought it would look at all "P"s and find it after that.. but i am wrong..  After doing the edit with INPUT i get this "doesn't contain a method named 'value'. ForEach-object { $_.value <<<< ("testtesttest")}"

Comment: try `$_.value = "some@email.her"`  `value` is a property, not a method, and you are trying to use it like a method.

Comment: YES!! it worked.. thank you tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has two problems:

1. The email input is an INPUT tag, not a P tag, so you need:

`$em = $doc.getElementsByTagName("input") |`

2. You are trying to set the value using a method invocation, but `value` is a property, not a method, so you need:

`$_.value = "some@email.her"`